# Rails : trigger a sound on any device

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, audio

I've been reviewing former posts on ways to play sounds that imply different elements that seem quite technical/arcane to me as a non specialist.

What I would like to do is simple : trigger a few basic sounds from a very limited preset library of sounds that I would have my users to hear as helpers : for instance, the noise of a cashing-machine cashing-in whenever they've correctly registered an order.
I don't want to get in any scenario where I would build such a library. I'm sure it must exist, somewhere, and I would be happy to learn how to use it simply from my app, maybe through JQuery.

I realise that not all browsers/devices would be able to render any such preset sound, but it doesn't matter. It's just an additional helper for users. If their browser doesn't feature such a capability, they'll have do without, but at least, part of my users can hear them...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [Ion.Sound](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/en.html) for example. Integration with Rails should be easy:

- include this JS library to Rails assets (place `ion.sound.js` or `ion.sound.min.js` to `app/assets/javascript`)
- copy `sounds` directory to `public` directory (in this case you can write direct path to sound files without Asset Pipeline prefixes)
- add JS code to play sounds as described in [examples](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/demo.html)

Seems like that's all.

Comment: I am supposed to trigger the sound from a .js.erb view, and that's in Coffeescript, starting with $...